# How to display all results of my MongoDB query --eval in bash shell without changing in parameters?

Tags: mongodb, bash, shell

When I execute my `--eval` MongoDB query in bash shell, it returns the 20 first results and then says `Type "it" for more`. However, I would like to display all of the results.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837673/how-to-execute-mongo-commands-through-shell-scripts) here explains how to query through bash terminal. In the comment section of the accepted answer, someone asks how to display more of the results. Another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705517/how-to-print-out-more-than-20-items-documents-in-mongodbs-shell) asks how to print out more than 20 documents but this changes the default options of MongoDB, something I don't wish to do.

This is the following shell command:

```
mongo --quiet myDB --eval "printjson(db.PatientsObservedMutations_hg38.find({Sample: 'test-exome-1_hg38'}).pretty().shellPrint())"
```

In short, is there a way to display all the results using the `--eval` in my bash shell after querying with mongoDB ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To print all the records, we can use `toArray()` method. It converts the iterator(returned by `find()` method) to an array.

The following query can get us the expected output:

```
mongo --quiet myDB --eval "printjson(db.PatientsObservedMutations_hg38.find({Sample: 'test-exome-1_hg38'}).toArray())"
```