# Why db.collection.find() in MongoDB Atlas does not return all the items?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

As title. It only return a certain number of items. This number is fixed. This occur both when I use the terminal and when I use ***model.find()*** in mongoose.

Comment: See if this answer helps:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705517/how-to-print-out-more-than-20-items-documents-in-mongodbs-shell

Comment: What is the code you are using?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're seeing is the returned cursor.

You can use `cursor.toArray()` [ref](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.toArray/#cursor-toarray) to get all the documents as an array.

In your terminal try using `db.collection.find().toArray();`