# `db.users.find({}, {username: 1})` Is not returning all the related Documents in Mongo Shell

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql

I have total 45 documents in the collection named `users`. Cant understood why the `db.users.find({}, {username: 1})` command returning only first 20 documents.[image]

I also tried the `db.users.find({}, {username: 1}).limit(40)` to test, but still it returning the same.

Comment: Type "it" to see more records

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MongoDB displays 20 documents max in terminal. You can type `it` to iterate over other elements and display them. You can type the command `DBQuery.shellBatchSize = 100` to increase this limit to 100.

Refer the following link to know more about this command [Change the mongo Shell Batch Size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-mongo-shell/index.html#change-the-mongo-shell-batch-size)

A similar query is also answered here [How to print out more than 20 items (documents) in MongoDB's shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705517/how-to-print-out-more-than-20-items-documents-in-mongodbs-shell)