# How do I set show more than 20 results in Intellij / DataGrip Mongo DB Shell

Tags: mongodb, intellij-idea, datagrip

This is related to [How to print out more than 20 items (documents) in MongoDB's shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705517/how-to-print-out-more-than-20-items-documents-in-mongodbs-shell). Right now I'm only seeing 20 items at a time returned from my IntelliJ MongoDB interactive shell. Things that I have tried:

- Confirming IntelliJ Preferences >> Tools >> Database >> Data Views does not have any 20 item limit.
- Executing `DBQuery.shellBatchSize = 1000;` in the IntelliJ MongoDB shell
- Adding `DBQuery.shellBatchSize = 1000;` to `.mongors.js` file in my home directory (as the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/mongo/#.mongorc.js-file) say).

How can I get remove this 20 item limit in IntelliJ MongoDB driver?

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/settings-tools-database-data-views.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since 2021.1 version you can change the value of `database.mongodb.page.size.limit` Registry option. To open Registry dialog use Help | **Find Action...** and type "Registry":

[image]

Comment: still the same solution for intellij 2022.3.3, thanks for sharing!

Comment: In PhpStorm 2023.1.2 option is absent.
Earlier was present

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I wanted to see more than 20 records in the 'preview window' when using the query console.

It's easy to miss but it's configurable here:

[image]